# How to install gitweb on Solaris?

Tags: gitweb

Friends,

I downloaded git and its dependency package from sunfreeware.com. Git installation was successful and it is working. I'm trying to configure via web. But gitweb appears to be not installed when i installed through sunfreeware packages.

Altenatively i downloaded git source from git clone http://www.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git

But when i try to compile getting error message. I doubt whether any dependency software needed for compilation.

Error:

root@shark /tmp/git #make
make: Fatal error in reader: Makefile, line 308: Unexpected end of line seen

Actual line in the Makefile:

```
GIT-VERSION-FILE: FORCE
    @$(SHELL_PATH) ./GIT-VERSION-GEN
-include GIT-VERSION-FILE

uname_S := $(shell sh -c 'uname -s 2>/dev/null || echo not')
uname_M := $(shell sh -c 'uname -m 2>/dev/null || echo not')
uname_O := $(shell sh -c 'uname -o 2>/dev/null || echo not')
uname_R := $(shell sh -c 'uname -r 2>/dev/null || echo not')
uname_P := $(shell sh -c 'uname -p 2>/dev/null || echo not')
uname_V := $(shell sh -c 'uname -v 2>/dev/null || echo not')
```

Please help me installing gitweb or source install

Thanks
Bala

Comment: The same error occurs if you try to install git itself by compiling from source. It seems to be because the Makefile assumes all sorts of GNU tools but Solaris has others. Installing them first may help - see http://www.scribd.com/doc/59936112/Build-Git-on-Solaris-9. Luckily I've been able to give up and move to a non-Solaris server, so I haven't tried it.